# how to create a new label when a button is pressed in pyqt5

Tags: python, pyqt5, designer

i have this code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'scroll_test.ui'
#
# Created by: PyQt5 UI code generator 5.15.4
#
# WARNING: Any manual changes made to this file will be lost when pyuic5 is
# run again.  Do not edit this file unless you know what you are doing.


from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(1034, 669)

        self.current_y = 200
        self.current_x = 390

        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(21, 131, 43);")
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")

        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")

        self.scrollArea = QtWidgets.QScrollArea(self.centralwidget)
        self.scrollArea.setWidgetResizable(True)
        self.scrollArea.setObjectName("scrollArea")
        self.scrollAreaWidgetContents = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.scrollAreaWidgetContents.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 997, 1218))
        self.scrollAreaWidgetContents.setObjectName("scrollAreaWidgetContents")

        self.verticalLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
        self.verticalLayout_2.setObjectName("verticalLayout_2")

        self.frame = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
        self.frame.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(0, 1200))
        self.frame.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.frame.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.frame.setObjectName("frame")

        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.frame)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(390, 150, 191, 141))
        self.pushButton.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(33, 37, 255);")
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")

        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.frame)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(320, -50, 351, 201))

        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Yu Gothic")
        font.setPointSize(50)

        self.label.setFont(font)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")

        self.verticalLayout_2.addWidget(self.frame)

        self.scrollArea.setWidget(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)

        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.scrollArea)

        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 1034, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")

        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)

        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")

        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.add_label)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "PushButton"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Mega Chat"))
    def add_label(self):
        self.new_label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.frame)
        self.new_label.setGeometry(self.current_x, self.current_y, 50, 50)
        self.new_label.setText("Mega Chat")
        
if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

im trying to create a new label and display it on the screen when the button is pressed but nothing happens when i press it. i can modify values of existing labels but i cant figure out how to make new ones while the program is running i have a starting x, y values and im trying to make a new object inside the function then set the geometry and text of the label the problem is just displaying the label on the screen and i cant figure out what im doing wrong.

Comment: New widgets that are not part of a layout and are created with a parent **must** be explicitly *shown*, either by `show()` or `setVisible(True)`. Note, though, that: you shall *always* use [layout managers](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/layout.html), as fixed geometries are discouraged, and, most importantly, you shall *never*, ***EVER*** edit files generated by pyuic (as clearly written in that warning), instead follow the official guidelines about [using Designer](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/designer.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the issue here is that you're not showing the label after adding it, you can fix that by adding

```
self.new_label.show()
```

at the end of your add_label function.